# Volume of gas at which relative fluctuation of gas density occurs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas

I have the following question:

> In what volume of gas occurs 10 % relative fluctuation of gas density
>   under pressure of $10^5\text{ Pa}$ and temperature of $293.15\text{ K}$?

I don't understand the topic but I assume this is about ideal gas. Can you please explain this to someone who has just high school physics knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute relative fluctuation of gas volume (which is the same as fluctuation of gas density here) by computing probabilities using entropy (or equivalently Gibbs energy) difference. The following [page](http://fc.retecivica.milano.it/~paolo.ripamonti/resources/Fluctuations.html) has explained all the steps.

The final formula would be: $\delta = \langle {(V - V_0)^2 \over V^2} \rangle = {1 \over N} $

In which $N$ is number of atoms which we can compute from ideal gas state equation: $N = {PV \over kT}$

So $\delta = \langle {(V - V_0)^2 \over V^2} \rangle = {k T \over P V}$

$\delta = \langle {(V - V_0)^2 \over V^2} \rangle = 0.01$

$V = {k T \over P \delta} = 4\times 10^{-24} ~\text m^3 = 4000 ~\text{nm}^3$

This volume is small; you need very few atoms to have such a huge fluctuations.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail where did the original values go? (Or how did we get to 0.01 and 4*10^-24.) The page you are linking to is above my level of understanding :- /

Comment: ${(V - V_0) \over V} = 0.1$ So approximately $\langle {(V - V_0)^2 \over V^2} \rangle = 0.01$

Comment: @Andrew123321 May I ask what grade are you in and where you see the question?

Comment: I see. Can you please also expand on 4*10^-24?

I am an undergraduate student of computer science and this is an excercise from physics class I've taken.

Comment: Well, $k$ is the Boltzmann constant $k = 1.38 \times 10^{-23} J/K$ , $T = 293.15 K$ , $P=10^5 Pa$ , $\delta = 0.01$. Just put them in the last formula.

Comment: @Azad, you have removed the correction I made \left/\right on the angled brackets. I am unsure why you have done this. ?

Comment: @UnkleRhaukus Yes, Thanks for your corrections but the  \left/\right made angle brackets appear lower than where they should be.

Comment: @UnkleRhaukus By the way what \left or \right do? Sorry, I should have told you before undoing them.

Comment: @Azad,\left/\right, around bracket delimiters makes the delimiters scale correctly to properly enclose the terms they are around . Without \left/\right the angled brackets, are too small.